# Poor Google indexing rank on website

Tags: wordpress, seo

I have bought the domain pousadafloresdocerrado.com.br to host a client's website. He is switching from floresdocerrado.pirenopolis.tur.br, his old website, to the new domain with a new website.

I have properly configured the sitemap.xml file, allowed robots.txt to search and index the pages and sent them to index on Google Webmasters.

I have set an unique metadescription and title for each page of the site. I've used the keywords that were most relevant for the business, based on the fact that it is a tourism inn. The keywords matches with the website's own url, the metadescription words and the website content. The website is mobile-friendly, and all of it's pages have hrefl translations to english and spanish.

And it still turns out that the website's positioning is ridiculously low, even on searches that its keywords matches with the site's url and title.

When someone searches "Pousada Flores do Cerrado" on Google it appears as 29th result, while the old web address (floresdocerrado.pirenopolis.tur.br) is the first one, and it also appears with sitelinks for the main site pages.

Where am I missing that ended resulting in this positioning? And how can I get my site to have sitelinks too? Does it have to be the first search result?

Comment: redirect the old site to the new site by way of 301 redirects. And read here https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83105?hl=en

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO.

Comment: Moving from Old domain to new domain you should have to follow these 7 steps  http://www.tech9logy.com/our-blog/7-steps-to-change-domain-/

Answer (score 1):

I recommend approaching [Google Webmater forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/webmasters) for your question. StackOverflow is not a perfect place for SEO or ranking issues.

And as for the site links: It is completely dependant on Google to determine sitelinks for any site. Sitelinks can appear on other than first rank as well.

Thanks